# Unnecessary genitive being used with 'suum'

Tags: syntax, pronouns, genitive, sentence-translation, reflexive-pronoun

I am not sure how to translate

> Augustus affirmāvit genūs suum ab Iove ortum esse.

One can logically conclude that this much of the sentence is correct...

> Augustus affirmed that ... from Jupiter had arisen.

genūs can only be genitive singular, and suum can only be accusative.

If I try to put this together the only way to put this together is

> Augustus affirmed that his knee had arisen from Jupiter.

My question is if this is actually the correct translation, then why didn't the author use genū instead of genūs?

Comment: genus (thus, with two short vowels) is nominative/accusative singular neuter and it means "birth, descent". Want to try again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are confusing [*gĕnu, -ūs*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dgenu) ("knee") and [*gĕnus, -ĕris*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dgenus1) ("origin, lineage, stock").

The latter is a 3rd declension neuter noun, so the accusative singular is the same as the nominative singular. Hence, to fill in the blank:

> Augustus affirmed that his lineage had arisen from Jupiter.

Comment: thanks... I guess there was a long mark typo in my book.  I was thinking that there was some mythology story I missed out on of Augustus being born in Zeus's knee or something...

Comment: @user062295 There probably was. :)

Comment: @user062295 Knowing what I do about mythology, I honestly wouldn't be surprised if that was actually a story. Sure sounds like one!